# Failed to build NuGet package...includes source and symbol file

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, nuspec

I am facing issue while packaging static content as part of NuGet.

I want to package Javascript files only as part of the NuGet package. Included the following entry inside the NuSpec file as shown below...

file src="*.js" target="Content\JS"

Included the csprok and corresponding NuSpec file inside the .Proj file.

Now when i try to run the following command (***msbuild packaging.proj***) it gives out the error saying

**error : Failed to build package. Ensure '...NuSpec' includes source and symbol files**

Not sure if i am missing something here...

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the NuGet package has to be packaged along with the binaries... once i include a mix of binaries and static content (CSS/JS) everything seems to be working fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out that we can use "NuGet Package Explorer" to create a NuGet package. This way we can add the static content only and it doesn't thrown any issues i was facing earlier.